# VBA outlook - retrieve email address from excel as recipient

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I would like to retrieve the email addresses from excel cells and copy them as recipients on outlook.

However, the "To" and "CC" on outlook are empty.

**input and output:**

Cell A1 is the email address which I want to **"send to"**.

Cell A2 is the email address which I want to **"CC to"**.

**my VBA code:**

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object




    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)



    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = Cells("A1")
        .CC = Cells("A2")
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"

    End With
    On Error GoTo 0


    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: When you execute a macro, does active sheet is sheet containing data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a recipient, not the To, CC or BCC properties. These properties contain the display names only. The Recipients collection should be used to modify this property. For example:

```
Sub CreateStatusReportToBoss()  
   Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem  
   Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
   Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)  
   Set myRecipient = myItem.Recipients.Add("Dan Wilson")  
   myItem.Subject = "Status Report"  
   myItem.Display  
End Sub
```

You may find the following articles helpful:

- [How To: Create and send an Outlook message programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/02/outlook-create-send-message/)
- [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/)

Comment: Thanks, I would like to dim all my object as object instead of outlook application though.

Comment: @Dmitry is correct.  I have used a script for 5 years with the To and CC properties.  The only error with his code was that "Cells("A1")" is invalid. see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove "On Error Resume Next" you can debug.  The following are invalid:

```
.To = Cells("A1")
.CC = Cells("A2")
```

Try

```
.To = Range("A1")
.CC = Range("A2")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had better luck with a [`Recipient`](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/):

```
'If not defined:
'olBCC=3
'olCC=2
'olTo=1

Set OutMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
Set myRecipient = OutMail.Recipients.Add(Range("A1"))
'myRecipient.Type = olTo
'This is default - use for clarity if desired
Set myRecipient = OutMail.Recipients.Add(Range("A2")) 
myRecipient.Type = olCC
```

If you wish to add multiple recipients, you will have to add them one at a time

Comment: Hi sean, it highlighted the word "Range" and error msg pop up " Expected: end of statement".

Comment: Many thanks, however, the "CC" row is empty. I show my revised code on the above. could you have a look please?

Comment: check that olCC is giving the value 2. `Option Explicit` will track down errors where a variable is not defined

Comment: Hi sean, I have added option explicit. There is no error in the code.