# How to set a cc Recipient?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Both the email addresses from cells A1 and A2 show up in "to" on Outlook.

How do I set cell A2 to "cc"?

**Input and output:**

Cell A1 is the email address which I want to "send to".

Cell A2 is the email address which I want to "CC to".

**VBA code:**

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Const olMailItem As Long = 0
Const olTo As Long = 1
Const olCC As Long = 2
Const olBCC As Long = 3

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim myRecipient As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail

    .To = OutMail.Recipients.Add(Range("A1"))
     myRecipient.Type = olTo

    .CC = OutMail.Recipients.Add(Range("A2"))
     myRecipient.Type = olCC

    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "This is the Subject line"

End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA outlook - retrieve email address from excel as recipient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28090655/vba-outlook-retrieve-email-address-from-excel-as-recipient)

Answer (score 2):

You are not correctly setting the recipient types:

```
With OutMail

    Set myRecipient = .recipients.Add(Range("A1"))
    myRecipient.Type = olTo

    Set myRecipient = .recipients.Add(Range("A2"))
    myRecipient.Type = olCC

    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "This is the Subject line"

End With
```